Ваше величество умерло ИЛИ ваше величество умер?
Ваше Величество умерло ИЛИ Ваше Величество умер?
Как правильно?

Его Величество умерли.

Поясните, пожалуйста, смысл этих загадочных слов!

Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Как вариант: Ваше Величество изволили умереть.



Ваше величество умерло ИЛИ ваше величество умер?

Ваше величество умерли.
Ваше величество умерли-с.
Ваше величество изволили умереть.
Ваше величество приказали долго жить.
Ваше величество изволили отдать душу Богу.
Ваше величество отдали душу Богу.
Ваше величество изволили почить в Бозе.
Ваше величество изволили отправиться в лучший мир.

И так далее и тому подобное, - варьируйте!
